# Select users having required roles only

Tags: mysql, sql

I have standard table with users->roles relations

```
user_id | role_id
----------------
1       |   1
1       |   2
1       |   3
2       |   1
2       |   3
3       |   1
3       |   2
4       |   1
4       |   2
4       |   3
4       |   4
```

For the clear comprehension

```
1: [1, 2, 3]
2: [1, 3]
3: [1, 2]
4: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to write a query returning users having only required roles. For example, if required roles are [1, 2, 3, 5] then only users 1, 2, 3 satisfy the condition because user 4 has the role 4 not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select user_id
from user_roles ur
group by user_id
having sum( role_id not in (1, 2, 3, 5) ) = 0;
```

I prefer this over `NOT EXISTS` because it returns the `user_id`s without duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use correlated subquery

```
 select * from tablename a
 where not exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.user_id=b.user_id and role_id not in (1,2,3,5))
```